# iOS RNCryptor (encrypting) and Node.JS jscryptor (decrypting)

Tags: ios, node.js, objective-c, rncryptor

I'm passing a base 64 string created with RNCryptor on iOS and am unable to decrypt it. When adding some console.logs to the Node.JS library's Decrypt function, it stops at the !_hmac_is_valid comparison. I can, however, use the .NET library to decrypt and the output is fine.

iOS

```
- (void) sendCommand: (NSString *) command {
    NSData *data = [command dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *key = @"1234567890123456789012";
    NSData *encryptedData = [RNEncryptor encryptData:data
                                        withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                                            password:key
                                               error:&error];

    if (currentPeripheral != nil && currentPeripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected) {
        [currentPeripheral writeValue:encryptedData forCharacteristic:currentCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];

    }

}
```

Node.JS

```
function decryptString(data) {
    const RNCryptor = require('jscryptor');
    const password = '1234567890123456789012';

    try {
        console.log(RNCryptor.Decrypt(data.toString('base64'), password).toString('ascii')); // undefined when trying to decrypt the iOS string
    }
    catch (e) {}
}
```

VB.NET test

```
Public Function DecryptString(encryptedString) As String
    Dim password = "1234567890123456789012"
    Dim decryptor As New Decryptor
    Dim decryptedData As String = decryptor.Decrypt(encryptedString, password)

    Return decryptedData
End Function
```

Comment: "a base 64 string created with RNCryptor on iOS and am unable to decrypt it." RNCryptor doesn't generate Base64. And the JavaScript implementation of RNCryptor doesn't accept Base64. It expects a bitArray. (The Encrypt function also returns a bitArray, not Base64.) I expect you have a Base64 encoding step that you didn't list above in the ObjC code, and you're missing a Base64 decoding step in the JavaScript.

Comment: @RobNapier. Yes, that's right. After I send the data out to the Node.js side, I convert it to b64 using .toString('base64') on the variable containing the data. The jscryptor library is expecting a b64 string so I didn't decode it from b64. I tested that works by using the library's encrypt function and then decrypting it from there and got valid data. However, I'm guessing something is still fundamentally different between what I'm getting out from iOS's encryption function vs. encrypting with the Node.js jscryptor library.

Comment: Sorry; I was thinking this was RNCryptor-js (which is a different RNCryptor implementation in JavaScript). My expectation is that you're not passing to the server quite what you think you're passing. That's the most common cause of this kind of issue. Check each step, and make sure that the data that comes out of ObjC is exactly the data that goes into the JavaScript. Any tiny change is sufficient to break the decryption. You didn't include the full output and input in your question.

Comment: The output I got after converting it to b64 was `AwHQbT+Ir2sMZhb0YhBsPyx0QWZqisDj9DW3qwRK/jYsu3pwHKg3GPqNemdwXB9WIi+oz4I8+AItW9XKrP1JlRGrwPOcvjYcL4LWBGe8lllQ38xpft4ksDXR2AAjXfvK12vNb+0D/OEMUJ25mEdKAIZXzj3y+CE9pLrYOD4as1eKbHLdLvx+hdqBne8JJS9USI4=`, I tried rncryptor-js, but for some reason sjcl.mode.cbc was undefined, so I left it for the time being. This decrypts for me if I pass it into rncryptor in a windows form app

Comment: When I encrypt "This is a test" with the password "1234567890123456789012", I get `AwE7XR6dzO9Pmf5l+DAeB3l8AruCmkU2ZSWUXCaBTjMH3rlBKg2zcbC951BjhlmsFW6oqSzJZ/dzR93R/jkrxhRBgMyR66+N3HjJAsbkzvDnpQ==`. Are you certain this is exactly the correct input and password? The length suggests you're encrypting some other string. Please post the exact code you're using. Every step of encryption has to be correct. It's impossible to guess what you're doing in the middle.

Comment: "This is a test" was for that jscryptor library to show I was able to encrypt/decrypt with that library. If I encrypt it with the iOS side, I get `AwHlT6gAh5eWwTJR2e0wUfZrd+8wGT8PRy4FO8Rs124r+2+AxQlIQ1Hvd/FQotZXcJALrWn0SK4Pa+tKtXdrHPC3Zx6cGK0wO1BFZaDr1/7YWg==`

Comment: When I plug the output I gave above into your jscryptor code, it decrypts. When I plug in your output, it fails verifying the hmac. That suggests you're doing something other than exactly what you're describing in the ObjC code. You need to give the exact ObjC you're using, including how you create the `data` variable and how you convert the output to an NSString. Without seeing the exact C# code, I can't guess how it's different than your Node example. I hate to harp on "exact" but every single byte of encryption is critical. Any step being even one byte wrong will break it. We need the code.

Comment: I updated the original iOS function and added the .net testing function to verify I can decrypt it

Comment: You never Base64 encode encryptedData, so where does the Base64 string you're describing (`AwHlT6gAh5eWwTJ...`) come from? Is the BLE peripheral you're writing to actually running the Node you're listing here? Assuming that the VB.NET is using rncryptor-cs, that doesn't accept Base64-encoded data, so when do you base64-decode it?

Comment: After it hits the node.js side, I get a "data" variable there on the message received event. I then call decryptString(data.toString('base64')) which contains the javascript procedure above. Let me update the javascript here to show how I'm using it

Comment: I removed the testing stuff and brought it up to date with my current node.js code without all the testing stuff to show how I'm using it exactly

Comment: And you've checked that the contents of `encryptedData` on the ObjC side are byte-for-byte identical to the contents of `data` on the Node side (I'm betting they are not precisely the same bytes; this is the most common mistake in encryption).

Comment: Aside from copying the b64 from the node side and decrypting it with the above .net function, not sure how to actually check that. Also, wouldn't the .net function not work either if the data became corrupt?

Comment: In regards to your other question, yes the ble peripheral is running the node program as well.

Comment: The .net function does not accept b64 (at least when I look at the code). So if you were just copying b64 to the .net side, it shouldn't work. If your b64 is, then I suspect you're applying b64 when you don't mean to. The way you test all of this is to carefully output the data (usually by logging) and feed it in by hand (usually in a test app where you give the data as a static string). I do not believe that your data is byte-for-byte identical. That may be due to B64 encoding when you shouldn't (or not when you should). But the key is to build tiny programs to test your beliefs.

Comment: (I've built several tiny programs in ObjC and Node to test what you're described here, and they work fine. They only fail when I put in the B64 data you've listed.)

Comment: I see. Yeah something might be going on, maybe something is time based? Cannot say for sure, but I noticed that encrypting "This is a test" is yielding a different b64 each time I encrypt it. Not sure if that's a setting or the algorithm I'm using in the above iOS function. Just wish I knew what was going on with the .net program to decrypt it vs what's going on with the node side. I was able to decrypt your b64 using the node program also. So I'm not sure entirely what's different now

Comment: Every time you encrypt with RNCryptor you'll get a different output. That's on purpose. The RNCryptor format includes some random values to ensure that's true (it's a critical security feature). So you want to take a single encryption and make sure it works with every decryptor. You can't check that all encryptors generate the same output (since they never will).

Comment: (BTW, in case there was any confusion, I'm the "RN" in RNCryptor. But I didn't write all the implementations. I just maintain the spec and a few of them.)

Comment: Just as an update, I found the missing link in the puzzle. JSCryptor has 10000 iterations set in the node_module and when I changed it to 10, it started decrypting.

Comment: 10000 is the correct value. If you have 10 somewhere that means your other RNCryptor implementations have been modified. It's somewhat ok to change the value, but everything has to agree as you found. (If your key is truly random and not something a human could type, then 10 is actually completely fine. If it's "random," and long, but typeable than 10 is bad but acceptable. If it's not random and not long, then 10 is pretty insecure and could be brute-forced.)